# Save and rehydrate state of .net web application

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a web application that has some state associated with it that may not be lost. So I thought I will use the `Application_Start` and `Application_End` events to rehydrate and store that state from/to a database. But I am testing in Azure and the `Application_End` is never called.

This is my test code global.asax:

```
public class Application : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("APPLICATION STARTED.");
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("APPLICATION ENDED.");
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {

    }
}
```

The "APPLICATION_END" is never shown in the application logs.

Comment: Note: if the state **must not** be lost: then, you need to persist to a reliable store **as you go**. Everything else is simply "this might work, on a good day". So as long as this is "it would be *more convenient* if the state was retained: fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could *try* using:

```
class Foo : System.Web.Hosting.IRegisteredObject
{
    public void Stop(bool immediate) {...}
}
```

with (once, during startup):

```
var obj = new Foo();
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(obj);
```

The `Stop` method *should* (or at least: *might*) be called when shutting down. You probably want to serialize the state when `immediate` is `false`.